# How to understand Fabric crash log

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I just started using Fabric for crash reports.  I dont understand how this is helping me understand where my crash is occuring.  I have symbols uploaded and they appear to be matching.  All I see however is CLSLog, how do I understand where my issue is occuring?  Here is an example:

```
Crashed: Threadpool worker
0  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1007b7560 CLSLog + 7077868
1  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1003b201c CLSLog + 2861736
2  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1003b201c CLSLog + 2861736
3  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1004102fc CLSLog + 3247496
4  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x10035cf18 CLSLog + 2513316
5  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1007babfc CLSLog + 7091848
6  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1002b1794 CLSLog + 1810976
7  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1002afc5c CLSLog + 1804008
8  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x100b24e50 CLSLog + 10672348
9  MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1002b1628 CLSLog + 1810612
10 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1003d8a94 CLSLog + 3020064
11 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1022de448 __cxa_throw + 2634216
12 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1023575c8 __cxa_throw + 3130216
13 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x10237d32c __cxa_throw + 3285196
14 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x10237b1c0 __cxa_throw + 3276640
15 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x102385310 __cxa_throw + 3317936
16 MineChatFormsLiteiOS           0x1023ed2d8 __cxa_throw + 3743864
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x187a4968c _pthread_body + 240
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x187a4959c _pthread_body + 282
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x187a46cb4 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you sharing your app's symbols to Apple when using Bitcode?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fabric. Please have a look at Apple's documentation how to read a crash report and its contaied stackshot : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html